# How to properly bind a ListView so that it's items can receive a background value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, listviewitem

I'm currently working on a small Video Poker app, partially because it's fun & because I needed a project for school.

Unless I missed something, my logic should be done, but now, as I'm turning my attention to the UI aspect of the app, I've hit a snag.

What I need/want my ListView to do is this:

- Not interact with mouseovers/mouse clicks performed by the user
- Be filled through code, the items need to be replaced each time the bet changes
- When the user has a winning hand, highlight it in the ListView by changing the BackGround property.

So far I've had "some" success, meaning I've been able to have it work so that I can select an item through mouse-clicks, after which the color changed, however I couldn't get it to work by changing the SelectedItem to the winning hand.

I've tried just about anything I can think of & I've hit a dead end.
I'm fairly sure it's somehow achieved through Binding data, but all my efforts so far have failed. I still lack quite a bit of both knowledge & experience when it comes to Databinding XAML elements.

If anyone here could help me out with a neat/clean/efficient way to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

**XAML:**

```
<ListView x:Name="lvTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Margin="10,10,0,0">
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="105" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HandNaam}"/>
        <GridViewColumn Width="45" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Betaling}"/>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

**C#:**

```
List<Hand> hands = new List<Hand>();
//Bet has been changed, (re-)populate the ListView
void Betchanged()
{
    hands.Clear();
    lvTest.ItemsSource = null;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        hands.Add(new Hand(Hand.hands[i], bet));
    }
    lvTest.ItemsSource = hands;
}

//Game ends
//After checking for a winning hand, highlight that hand in the ListView
private void EndGame()
{
    //Do some stuff

    //Check if there's a winning hand
    int winnings;
    Hand hand = null;
    winnings = Poker.FindWin(splK, hands, out hand); //out hand is of type Hand

    //If there's a winning hand, highlight it in the ListView
    if (hand != null)
    {
        foreach (Hand h in lvTest.Items)
        {
            if (h.HandName == hand.HandName)
            {
                //This seems like the most logical (maybe not most efficient) way to find the correct item in the ListView
                //Here's where the Background property for the ListViewItem should be changed
            }
        }
    }
    //Do some more stuff
}
```

PS: The current Template style in my XAML is what's overriding my ListViewItem's hover/click interactions.

Edit: Here's a screenshot with a possible scenario when the Background for a ListViewItem should be changed:
[image: Example scenario]

Comment: What type is `hands`?

Comment: It's `List<Hand>`, added it in my question as well. Although it was kind of already in my question as the creation of the elements in hands is: `hands.Add(new **Hand**(....)` :)

Comment: Not as obvious as you think as `Add()` method is implemented by any `ICollection` class, of which there are many and `List<T>` is just one. ;)

Comment: @toadflakz Never said it was obvious, I just said it was - sort of - there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ItemsSource` in order to notify the control via the `Binding` that it's contents have changed, needs to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. At the moment, the most common generic collection to implement this interface is `ObservableCollection<T>`.

`hands` should be an `ObservableCollection<Hand>` rather than a `List<Hand>`.

**Edit based on comment**:

WPF `Binding` works on notifications of changes. For properties, this means implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on classes that need to notify that their properties have changed. Your `Hand` class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for when the specific value you want to change has changed.

Presentation logic should be handled by the `View` class (or code related to the `View` like a `Converter`) so you should bind to your Model property value and convert it to a `Brush` object using a Converter.

You could just expose a `Brush` on your Model object but that would be breaking MVVM pattern as a `ViewModel` is not supposed to have View-specific/presentation technology classes embedded in them in order to be presentation technology agnostic.

**Second edit based on second comment:**

Converters are code that convert values from one type to the other by implementing `IValueConverter` interface ( [MSDN : IValueConverter documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ). They need to be declared as resources in your XAML and referenced using `StaticResource` directives in the `Binding`.

An excellent tutorial on this (and other basic WPF subjects) can be found at [WPFTutorial.com - Value Converters](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

Comment: I see, however I'm not sure you understand my question completely, what I'm looking for is a way to change the Background color of a ListViewItem (probably by binding it's value to a property in my `Hand` class), not when the collection changes.

Comment: I had something yesterday with which I was using INotifyPropertyChanged, if I remember correctly it was triggering fine but not changing the color properly. I'm not too sure if I placed my binding in the correct location in my XAML though. The code I had yesterday: `<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={SelectedColor}"/>`

Comment: That's not quite right (but close). Have a look at the tutorial I've linked - it goes through how it works. Essentially you bind to your Model value and inject a piece of code to convert it to the right value before it's returned to the control itself.

Comment: I've seen those links before, however I still can't figure out how to apply the binding to a template, as my ListView doesn't get populated until runtime.

Comment: Define an `ItemTemplate` using `<ListView.ItemTemplate>`.

Comment: Used an inline `<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>` instead, but that worked like a charm, it was as I feared, I just had my binding in the wrong place >.< Thanks though :)